# Can't find keras.layers.containers.Sequential()

Tags: keras, theano

i can't find the class keras.layers.containers.Sequential() in Keras 2.0.4. i have the error 'ImportError: cannot import name containers'
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYPkB.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to use the [Sequential Model](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

But I really recommend to go straight for the [Funciontal API Model](https://keras.io/models/model/), which you will need for any kind of model with branches.

```
from keras.models import Model
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i found that previous version of Keras used this class. Newest versions doesn't include this class.

Comment: Yeah sure i'm new in Stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 2):

install TensorFlow with conda

`conda install tensorflow`